# Boosting template based on search term

Tags: content-search

What is the best way to boost a template (in standard values?) when a specific search term is entered?

eg. when a user searches on "training *events*" I would like to boost all "Event" template pages.

I was hoping this could have been done with "Item Rules" but I could not find the parameters in the rule set editor.

Comment: Do you mean a content search from a code (programmatically) or search at the Content  Editor interface?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think your answer is here. Create a new search rule for when template = Events, boost results. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/search_result_boosting

Comment: In a content search programatically. I am using Solr, but I am hoping the search engine doesn't matter.

Comment: As long as you use the ContentSearchManager, all changes are translated to the underlying search provider. So the provider Lucene, SOLR or Azure search doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we speak about the search that implimented in the code, you can use something like below:

```
public List<SearchResultItem> Search(string keyword)
{
    var sparePartsIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(IndexName);
    var sparePartsSearchContext = sparePartsIndex.CreateSearchContext();

    var predicateRoots = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();

    //Here you can put your conditions

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
    {

         if (keyword.Contains("root") || keyword.Contains("roots"))
         {
              predicateRoots = predicateRoots.Or(itm => (itm.TemplateName == "Highlights Root").Boost(5));
              predicateRoots = predicateRoots.Or(itm => (itm.TemplateName != "Highlights Root").Boost(4));
          }

          if (keyword.Contains("high") || keyword.Contains("high"))
          {
              predicateRoots = predicateRoots.Or(itm => (itm.TemplateName == "Highlight").Boost(5));
              predicateRoots = predicateRoots.Or(itm => (itm.TemplateName != "Highlight").Boost(4));
           }
     }

     var queryable = sparePartsSearchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicateRoots);

     var searchresults = queryable.GetResults();

     return searchresults.Hits.Select(x => x.Document).ToList();
}
```

I've implemented that on the test environment and it works for me:

[image: result of executing the search method]

We need to understand that method is implemented as an example and conditions can be more flexible, without a hardcodes.